# Initializing and comparing an int dependent on the user's parameters

Tags: initialization

**A** and **B** are integers. I want to check if **A** is a multiple of **B**. However, if the range of random numbers and **B** is determined by the user, what value should I initialize **A** as?

I assumed using -1 but this does not work if the user entered positive ranges and **B** as -1. -1 is a multiple of -1 but it is not in range of, say, 1-10.

```
b = *int input from user*;

a = random_number_of_certain_range();
while(a % b != 0) {
    a = random_number_of_certain_range();
}
print "A is a multiple of B";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to initialize it at all.

You can take the input b and range from the user and subsequently find the value of a from a range. Use a do-while loop instead.

```
do
{
    a = random_number_of_certain_range();
}while(a % b != 0) ;
```

Comment: I believe you need to initialize A so that it can be compared in the while statement. Does this mean that I will need to initialize A to zero before entering the do while loop?

Comment: @MarcoLau You do not need to initialize it, you just need to declare it. The initialization is happening in the do-while loop